# Widget doesn't launch service when being clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I'm creating a widget for my app but it refuses to work.
This widget launching an configuration activity when it's being created, and when you click it, it should start a IntentService I've created.
But when I click it, it doesn't start the service! I tried to change this pending intent to an intent that would launch Google and it works.

Some code:

**AppWidgetProvider XML**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure="com.eladaharon.android.lary.widget.LaryWidgetConfigurationActivity"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_1x1"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

**Manifest declaration**

```
<activity
            android:name=".widget.LaryWidgetConfigurationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:enabled="true" android:name="widget.LaryWidgetCheckService" />

        <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
        <receiver android:name=".widget.LaryWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
```

**AppWidgetProvider class**

```
public class LaryWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch service
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LaryWidgetCheckService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_1x1);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_check_button, pendingIntent);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName("com.eladaharon.android.lary.widget",
                        ".SalaryWidgetConfigurationActivity"),
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName("com.eladaharon.android.lary.widget",
                        ".LaryWidgetConfigurationActivity"),
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        Editor edit = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERNCES_WIDGET_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            edit.remove(String.valueOf(appWidgetIds[i]));
        }
        edit.commit();
    }

    public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int appWidgetId) {

        // Create an Intent to launch service
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LaryWidgetCheckService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
        // to the button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_1x1);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_check_button, pendingIntent);

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

}
```

**Handler that being called on the configuration activity end**

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(LaryWidgetConfigurationActivity.this);
            LaryWidgetProvider.updateAppWidget(LaryWidgetConfigurationActivity.this, appWidgetManager,
                    mAppWidgetId);

            // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
        }
    };
```

**The service I want to run on click**

```
public class LaryWidgetCheckService extends IntentService {
    private int mAppWidgetId;

    public LaryWidgetCheckService(String name) {
        super("WorkplaceService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        // If they gave us an intent without the widget id, just bail.
        if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            return;
        }

        // Running some code
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate this world!!!
If you'll look again in the manifest you can notice that I wrote widget.SERVICENAME instead of .widget.SERVICENAME!!!

I've Spent a whole day on this!

Thanks for everyone who tried to help!

Comment: I hate it too. I made the same mistake like you did; but at least I lost half a day!

Answer (score 0):

Widget runs in another process, and you are sending an explicit intent that will works only inside your application. The reason of why the intent to launch google page in the web browser is because this is another type of intent that will involve broadcast receiver and it's propagated system wide to see if someone responds.

I think that you must declare a broadcast receiver in your service and fire that intent from your widget.

Comment: I tried to replace the service with an activity from my app and it does work so I think it has nothing to do with what you've said: 
`Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChooseActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);`